# Invert web page colours in Opera

Tags: browser, opera

I want to have inverted colours in Opera (including pictures) for browsing web content. How can I achieve that?

I found in [How to invert web pages colour scheme in Firefox?](https://superuser.com/questions/550687/how-to-invert-web-pages-colour-scheme-in-firefox) another that one should use this line

```
html { -webkit-filter: invert(); }
```

But I have no idea where I should put it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Opera's **developer tools / code inspector** by pressing <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd>+<kbd>**Shift**</kbd>+<kbd>**I**</kbd>.

Then right click where it you see the `<html>` line begin, and choose "Edit as HTML".

> [image]

At the end, find where `<head>` begins. Paste in the following:

```
<style>html { -webkit-filter: invert(); }</style>
```

Example using this exact page:

> [image]

Click out, and it works ([click here for a full size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5zwg.png)):

[image]

Remember of course that this will not save upon refreshing the page. What you're doing is editing **local HTML**.

Comment: Are there an extension which does this copy and paste automatically?

Comment: @JānisErdmanis Not to my knowledge, no.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/high-contrast/djcfdncoelnlbldjfhinnjlhdjlikmph
(in Chrome, Opera , Vivaldi, and other Chromium-powered browsers) ,
or use Vivaldi which has the feature built-in. 
(though not as elegant a solution as in classic Opera)