# How to conditionally (un)invert colors on inverted websites?

Tags: firefox, colors

Some web pages tend to use inverted colour schemes, i.e. light text on dark background (or vice versa, if your system theme is "inverted"). Discussions about the pros and cons of this aside, the abrupt change from this to its inverse when switching tabs or windows is rather stressful to the eyes, so how can I automatically re-invert websites using this while preferably retaining as much of the original colours as possible?

The tool [NegativeScreen](http://arcanesanctum.net/negativescreen/) does a pretty decent job at this (especially its "smart inversion"), but it is both triggered manually *and* applies globally and thus is not helpful on a multi-monitor system where one window is inverted and the other not.

Is there any way to achieve something similar via a *conditional* userstyle, greasemonkey script or even better an addon, such that *only* sites with inverted text-to-background colouring are un-inverted?

Ideally, the solution would automatically check a site's CSS, compare a measure of text and background colour such as [lightness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) and then swap that if adequate.

**edit** For clarification: I am *not* asking about simply [inverting web page colours](https://superuser.com/questions/550687/how-to-invert-web-pages-colour-scheme-in-firefox), I am asking about how to *automatically* do this only if the original theme is inverted to start with.

Comment: There are a couple of Firefox plugins that invert colors: Aniverto or BlankYourMonitor. Is that the kind of thing you mean?

Comment: @Ash They're a first crude step, but as far as I understood their function, they are manual (maybe even global across Firefox) and either just swap/invert text & background colour instead of inverting e.g. the [lightness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to invert web pages colour scheme in Firefox?](http://superuser.com/questions/550687/how-to-invert-web-pages-colour-scheme-in-firefox)

Comment: @manjesh23 That only shows how to _manually_ invert the display, not automatically only for inverted sites only